# Is there a limit for fragment cache on Heroku Dev?

Tags: caching, heroku

I am using Heroku Dev (the free version) for my rails application.
For performance, I use lots of fragment caches.
Is there a limit for the size of fragment caches?

Also, where is the fragment cache stored? I didn't set any configuration for that. And there's no tmp directory on Heroku App.

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragment caching uses the same `Rails.cache` store that the rest of your application uses. By default, Rails uses a memory store with a 32mb limit, but if you set a different store (e.g. `config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store`) the limits are different. Notably, most Memcache stores have a 1MB per-key size, so you can't store a single fragment larger than that.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores

Comment: you should checkout this guide for caching on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies . It's recommended you use an external backing service for caching

Comment: @ctshryock Yep, very familiar with it. Didn't think diving into cache stores or strategies was relevant here…seems like the OP was merely unaware of the cache store configuration at all.

Comment: was suggesting OP look into it, not yourself. In hindsight that's not clear :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use **memcache** on Heroku for fragment caching to great effect. I'd recommend the free [Memcachier](https://addons.heroku.com/memcachier) plan with a  25 MB Bucket.

```
$ heroku addons:add memcachier:dev
```

After some research I'm using these settings in my production.rb.

```
# config/production.rb
# Caching
#
# Explicit Requires
require 'memcachier'
require 'dalli'

# Global enable/disable all memcached usage
config.perform_caching = true

# Disable/enable fragment and page caching in ActionController
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Full error reports are disabled
config.consider_all_requests_local = false

# The underlying cache store to use.
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, { :compress => true }

# The session store is completely different from the normal data cache
# config.session_store = :dalli_store # REVIEW: Does this imply infinite sessions?

# HTTP Caching
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
  :allow_reload => false
}

# Gemfile
group :production do
  # Memcached using Memcachier on Heroku
  gem 'memcachier'
  gem 'dalli'
end
```

Hope this helps.